# Firestore simple leaderboard function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm tring to write a cloud function that ranks my users under the /mobile_user node by earned_points and assigns them a rank. I have successfully done this but now i want to write those same 10 users to another node called leaderboard. How can i accomplish this?

Here is my current function which already ranks them from 1 to 10:

```
    exports.leaderboardUpdate2 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{
  const updates = [];
  const leaderboard = {};

  const rankref = admin.firestore().collection('mobile_user');
  const leaderboardRef = admin.firestore().collection('leaderboard');

  return rankref.orderBy("earned_points").limit(10).get().then(function(top10) {
      let i = 0;
      console.log(top10)
      top10.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        const r = top10.size - i;
        console.log(childSnapshot)
        updates.push(childSnapshot.ref.update({rank: r}));
        leaderboard[childSnapshot.key] = Object.assign(childSnapshot, {rank: r});
        i++;
        console.log(leaderboard)
      });
      updates.push(leaderboardRef.add(leaderboard));
      return Promise.all(updates);
    }).then(() => {
      res.status(200).send("Mobile user ranks updated");
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("Error updating ranks.");
    });
});
```

This successfully updates the /mobile_user node where all my users are but i want to "export" those 10 users to the leaderboard node once the function executes.

(Note that the leaderboard node should have only 10 records at all times)

Comment: What is `updates` in the above code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it is an empty array to get pushed

Comment: OK, thanks for that updated code. What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your Cloud Function:

Firstly you cannot directly use the `childSnapshot` object (neither with `Object.assign` nor directly) to create a new document. You have to use `childSnapshot.data()`, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot

Secondly, you use `childSnapshot.key` while it should be `childSnapshot.id`, see the same document than above.

Finally, note that, with your code structure, the `users` document are added as maps under a unique `leaderboard` document. I am not sure it is exactly what you want, so you may adapt your code for this specific point.

So the following should work:

```
exports.leaderboardUpdate2 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const updates = [];
  const leaderboard = {};

  const rankref = admin.firestore().collection('mobile_user');
  const leaderboardRef = admin.firestore().collection('leaderboard');

  return rankref
    .orderBy('earned_points')
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    .then(function(top10) {
      let i = 0;
      console.log(top10);
      top10.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        const r = top10.size - i;
        updates.push(childSnapshot.ref.update({ rank: r }));
        leaderboard[childSnapshot.id] = Object.assign(childSnapshot.data(), {
          rank: r
        });
        i++;
      });
      updates.push(leaderboardRef.add(leaderboard));
      return Promise.all(updates);
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).send('Mobile user ranks updated');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error updating ranks.');
    });
});
```

---

Following your comment, here is a new version, that writes a doc, in the `leaderboard` Collection, for each `mobile_user`. Note that we use a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) and together with the `set()` method, as follows: `leaderboardRef.doc(childSnapshot.id).set()`

```
exports.leaderboardUpdate2 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const updates = [];
  const leaderboard = {};

  const rankref = admin.firestore().collection('mobile_user');
  const leaderboardRef = admin.firestore().collection('leaderboard');

  return rankref
    .orderBy('earned_points')
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    .then(function(top10) {
      let i = 0;
      console.log(top10);
      top10.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        const r = top10.size - i;
        updates.push(childSnapshot.ref.update({ rank: r }));

        updates.push(
          leaderboardRef.doc(childSnapshot.id).set(
            Object.assign(childSnapshot.data(), {
              rank: r
            })
          )
        );

        i++;
      });

      return Promise.all(updates);
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).send('Mobile user ranks updated');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error updating ranks.');
    });
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. However, like you said i am not trying to add the document under a unique doc but instead as 10 individual documents under the leaderboard doc. Could you point me to the right direction in my code?